# Installing Python package documentation

Tags: python, documentation, distutils

I'm publishing a few Python packages internally and I would like to include API documentation, currently in `.rst` form, but might go for Sphinx-generated HTML in the future. I need more details than I can reasonably put into a docstring (background info, tutorial examples, etc), so I've written it out long-hand.

I have a simple `distutils`-based `setup.py` where I pull in the text files, but I'm not sure where to put them on the target system (I target Windows, Linux and Mac.)

Is there a convention in the Python world for installing API docs alongside packages? Or are docs generally assumed to only be available online?

Any ideas welcome, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037828/writing-a-help-for-python-script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996235/python-help-command

Comment: Thanks! I have docstrings in place and I'm shipping libraries, not scripts, so argparse isn't applicable. I'd like to include API documentation, but I don't know where to deploy it -- I didn't see anything applicable in the answers you posted.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183692/

I guess the answer is "no"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing docs is not supported by distutils.  These days it seems more important to publish them online than to install them on the target system though, so if you’re set up to use Reat The Docs or upload docs to PyPI, you’re good.

Comment: Thanks Éric, I suspected that was the case. These are internal libraries, so public repos are not an option, unfortunately :-/

Comment: You can still benefit from using Sphinx and have your CI system buld and push the docs to an internal web server.  You can even use the Read The Docs code to have a company-wide RTD instance, we did that!